# How to calculate the point spread function used in function ImageDeconvolve

Tags: image-processing

## Question Background

- [How can estimate the PSF function to deblur an image of plate licence of a car](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52387/how-can-estimate-the-psf-function-to-deblur-an-image-of-plate-licence-of-a-car)

It was marked as duplicate.

- [How to enhance a fuzzy image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77169/how-to-enhance-a-fuzzy-image)

I don't very agree the current [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83385/21532) of [@2012rcampion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/21750/2012rcampion):

> In summary, **deconvolution can recover information in certain cases,
>   but cannot improve image *quality***.

There are many example in documentation of [`ImageDeconvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageDeconvolve.html),such as following screenshot:
http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-07-13-11-36-21.png

Or this:

http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-07-13-11-36-40.png

Its not only recover information in certain cases, but also improve image quality.So I think the keypoint is get the appropriate model of the blur image.**As the problem is very important and it seem there are no solution for it still,I post it here again for a professional answer.**

## Question

How to get the $ker$ used in function `ImageDeconvolve`,which can be a image or a matrix?

I provide a beauty for test here,which maybe make your mouth water but don't forget our purpose please.

#### Original image:

[image]

#### Blure image

[image]

Actually I use **Gaussian Blur** with 6-pixels to get it in Photoshop.But I cannot restore it by

```
ImageDeconvolve[blurImg, GaussianMatrix[n]]
```

It seem we need more smart method to get the $ker$.And [This website](http://www.juew.org/deblurFamousPhoto.html) have some picture for code test too.The picture is from the web.

[image]

Desire a universal solution from expert.

Comment: So, Liu Yifei... :)

Comment: @J.M. Little strange you know her.

Comment: I know a lot of strange things. ;) (And no, I did not do Google Image Search.)

Comment: Your image seems blurred much more that what *Mathematica* gives for a `GaussianMatrix[6]` blur.

Comment: @Young As I see,it more like `GaussianMatrix[10]`.[See this test](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-07-13-13-57-22.png)

Comment: "Desire a universal solution from expert." Good luck with that. There is extensive literature on "blind deconvolution". It's difficult. Read the comments to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95164/challenge-deblurring-images, and this paper: http://jstarck.free.fr/Blind07.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enhance a fuzzy image](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77169/how-to-enhance-a-fuzzy-image)? Or at least the one I referenced above about blind deconvolution (which is what this question is asking)

Comment: [Here](http://www.siam.org/books/fa03/) is an interesting book...

Comment: @blochwave Maybe you are right.This two post have some place overlaping.But I don't think that post have an answer I want and I have some diffrence opinion from it.So post it again. :)

Comment: This question appears to be about image processing itself rather than implementing an existing algorithm in *Mathematica*.  Perhaps it would be better suited to [DSP.SE]?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sometimes it's hard to get a clear line. :)

Comment: @yode Pardon me, but I don't understand the meaning of your comment.  I put this on hold at least temporarily.

Comment: Incidentally this *might* come into play here, I don't know: [(15596)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15596/121)

Answer (score 6):

**Update**

```
blurredLiuYifei =<OP Blurred Image>;
ListLogPlot@Table[{i, imageBlurMSE[LiuYifei, blurredLiuYifei, GaussianMatrix[i]]}, 
                  {i, 1,15, 0.1}]
```

[image]

```
resLiuYifei = 
 ImageDeconvolve[blurredLiuYifei, GaussianMatrix[10], 
    Method -> #] & /@ {"DampedLS", "Tikhonov", "TSVD", "Wiener"};
ImageAssemble[{LiuYifei, blurredLiuYifei, resLiuYifei[[4]]}]
```

[image]

---

Here's a test:

```
LiuYifei = <originalImage>;

image = ImageAdjust@ImageResize[LiuYifei, 256];
blurredImage = ImageConvolve[image, GaussianMatrix[5]];

imageBlurMSE[im1_, im2_, ker_] := 
 ImageDistance[ImageAdjust@im1, 
  ImageAdjust@ImageDeconvolve[im2, ker, Method -> "RichardsonLucy"], 
  DistanceFunction -> "MeanSquaredEuclideanDistance"]

ListLogPlot@
 Table[{i, imageBlurMSE[image, blurredImage, GaussianMatrix[i]]}, {i, 1, 10, 0.1}]
```

[image]

```
res = ImageDeconvolve[blurredImage, GaussianMatrix[5], Method -> {"DampedLS", 0.002}];

ImageAssemble[{image, blurredImage, res}]
```

[image]

Drawn heavily from the following:

[Challenge: deblurring images](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95164/challenge-deblurring-images/95171#95171)

[Image Restoration](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26823/image-restoration/26852#26852)

Comment: Maybe you want to find the suitable value of `GaussianMatrix[n]`，but note [this](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-07-13-13-52-02.png).And this post for a solution to find the $ker$ even I don't tell you this is a *Gaussian Blur* :)

Comment: I think "drawn heavily from the following" could be made clearer - you've just copied my code from [95171](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95164/challenge-deblurring-images/95171#95171)

Comment: I used method `{"DampedLS", 0.002}` from http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26823/image-restoration/26852#26852 which produced a better result and as I said in the lower part it was a test of a starting point